# Is it possible to force EF to cancel Committing in case a dependent entity does not exist anymore?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I want to create a new entity upon an existing of another entity in EntityFrameWork.

For instance, let's say I want to create barEntity object if fooEntity with ID=999 exists in Db:

```
var fooEntity =GetFooByID(999);

if (fooEntity != null)
{
  var barEntity = new Bar()
        {
            Sweetness = 8,
            Bitterness = 5,
            // goes on...
        }

 SaveBarEntity(barEntity); 
}
```

My concern is what is fooEntity does not exist anymore at the time I call SaveBarEntity(barEntity);

**Question:**
Is it possible to force EntityFramework somehow so that if fooEntity does not exist in the Db at the time of Save, it should throw an exception?

(To me it sounds like to make the fooEntity part of 'unit of work'. But how it is achievable in Entity Framework? )

Comment: is there a relation between foo and bar in the database?

Comment: Daryal, no. But does it make a big difference. The idea is, EF should fail if the loaded entity does not exist anymore in the Db -regardless if there is a relationship or not.

Comment: it makes a big difference; if there is a relation between foo and bar, EF will throw an exception will not commit.

Comment: I understand, but I am thinking of a way that can be generic which would fit regardless of an existence of relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, as there is no relation between `Foo` and `Bar`in the database, the only way is to create insert and update database triggers for `Bar` table to check whether related `Foo` entity exists.
In order to pass related `Foo` entity Id to database, you need to modify Save behaviour of EF to pass the id to the context of DB.

This really needs much effort; I think it is better for you to create a relationship between `Foo` and `Bar` in your model (which seems a proper way since it seems there is a relation between Foo and Bar).

Answer (score 0):

It is unnecessary work, but you could perform an update on the Foo record.

```
var fooEntity =GetFooByID(999);

if (fooEntity != null) {
    var barEntity = new Bar() {
        Sweetness = 8,
        Bitterness = 5,
        // goes on...
    };

    SaveBarEntity(barEntity); 
    SaveFooEntity(fooEntity); // If necessary, do something to make sure EF performs an update
}
```